# How to find exact string with no leading or trailing character

Tags: shell-script, grep, wildcards

i want to check if a line contains any of following strings apple or pie with condition explained below ,

```
aaaa bbbbb applezzzz           this should be treated as invalid

aaaaapple dddddd               invalid case

aaaa vvvvv apple       valid case
apple                  valid case (space just after apple)       
appleY                 if Y is present just after apple , it is also treated valid , Y could also be symbol like $
```

i have tried grep

```
grep 'apple\|appleY\|appple ' <<< $line
grep 'pie\|pieY\|pie ' <<< $line
```

but this satisfy invalid cases

Comment: How about `grep -P '\bappleY?\b'`? It will match any instance of apple or appleY that is preceded and followed by a non-word character.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GNU `grep`, you can grep for a whole word with the `-w` option and specify multiple patterns:

```
grep -w -e apple -e appleY -e pie -e pieY
```

You can also combine them in a single regular expression:

```
grep -w 'appleY\?\|pieY\?'
```

The `Y?` here means "optionally followed by Y"

You can get rid of the escaping by using extended regular expressions with the `-E` options:

```
grep -w -E 'appleY?|pieY?'
```